# Issue while comparing two dates in swift

Tags: swift, date

i'm trying to compare two date, one is coming from backend and second one is current date. But it is not showing me correct result, like my First date is `Jan 26, 2020` and current is `Jan 27,2020`, it should not add first date in my array. I only want those dates which are above from current date. My code for comparison is this,

```
for date in dateRange
{
    let availableDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
    //self.datesArray.append(availableDate + " | \(dateTime.startTime ?? "") - \(dateTime.endTime ?? "")")
    let dates = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
    let results = formatter.string(from: dates)
    if availableDate <= results
    {
        print("Past Date")
    }
    else
    {
        print(availableDate)
        print(results)
        self.datesArray.append(availableDate)
    }
}
```

For every iteration it adds date in dateArray, i don't know why?

Comment: you should use the date formate `MMM dd, yyyy` instead of `EEEE, MMM d, yyyy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty bad idea to convert dates to String and compare those.

Besides the string format is not comparable anyway (e.g. `Feb` is less than `Jan`)

Compare the dates

```
for date in dateRange {            
   let now = Date()
   if date <= now {
       print("Past Date")
   } else {
       print(date)
       print(now)
       self.datesArray.append(date) // declare datesArray as [Date]
   }
}
```

or simpler

```
let filteredDates = dateRange.filter{ $0 > Date() }
self.datesArray.append(contentsOf: filteredDates)
```

Comment: Thanks you safe my time. @vadian

Answer (score 0):

To check for dates, by date only and not time, that are after today use the built in Date type rather than strings and make use of the Calendar class

```
let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let datesArray = dateRange.filter { calendar.compare($0, to: now, toGranularity: .day) == .orderedDescending}
```

For best result you should set the `timeZone` property to the time zone of the incoming dates